# Counting symbols and empty lines from input text via gets

Tags: c

The program should print the number of empty lines and certain operators from the input text. I got the problem of empty lines fixed but I'm facing issues with the opperators. I guess it is something wrong with the break. I would appreciate any good ideas for fixing the code. Sorry if such a thread already exists but I checked and couldn't get a solution. Thanks in advance!

```
    char c,line[300];
int emptyLine = 0;      
int operators = 0;
printf("Input your text and press ctr+Z on a new line when done: \n");
        while(gets(line)) { 
        int i = 0;emptyLine++;
        for (i = 0; i < strlen(line); i++) {
            if(line[i] == '+'|| line[i] == '-' || line[i] == '/' || line[i] == '*' || line[i] == '%') 
            {
                operators++;    
            }
            if (line[i] != '\n' && line[i] != '\t' && line[i] != ' ') {
                emptyLine--;
                break;
                }
            }
            } 
    printf("The number of empty lines is: %d",emptyLine);
    printf("\nThe number of opperators is: %d",operators);
```

Comment: If a line has a space before an operator, you don't count the operator because of the break.

Comment: Well tried but when I type some text followed by enter and enter + ctrZ it returns '-' value for emptylines since it does the check for every elemnt and reduces the value of emptyLine by 1.I do not want that.. :)

Comment: I'm guessing the break is the main reason of the problem, as well but removing does not fix it..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
char c,line[300];
int emptyLine = 0;      
int operators = 0;
printf("Input your text and press ctr+Z on a new line when done: \n");
while(gets(line)) { 
    bool isEmpty = true;  // Assume empty line
    for (int i = 0; 0 != line[i]; i++) {
        if (!isspace(line[i])) {
            isEmpty = false;   // Line not empty
        }
        if (line[i] == '+'|| line[i] == '-' || line[i] == '/' || line[i] == '*' || line[i] == '%') {
            operators++;    
        }
    }
    if (isEmpty) {
        emptyLine += 1;
    }
}
printf("The number of empty lines is: %d",emptyLine);
printf("\nThe number of operators is: %d",operators);
```

Comment: Never ever ever ever **ever** use `gets`! It does absolutely no length checking, so it is literally impossible to use without opening a security hole. In fact, many systems that notice `gets` being used will print warnings when running a program with it. Instead, use `fgets` with `stdin` as the file pointer. `char line[100]; fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);`.